# Curl failure with socks proxy through SSH tunnel between EC2 instances : "curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack."

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, ssh, proxy, socks

I am seeing curl issues while setting up a socks proxy through a simple SSH tunnel between two EC2 instances in AWS.

```
box1 $ ssh -v -D 12345 ubuntu@box2 -N
[...]
```

The socks proxy seems to be running properly on port 12345, now when I try to curl through it:

```
box1 $ curl -x socks5h://localhost:12345 www.google.com
curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.
```

Back on the ssh -D window, this error appears when I run the curl command :

```
debug1: Connection to port 12345 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 1: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 12345 for www.google.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 36240 to 127.0.0.1 port 12345, nchannels 2
```

Can anybody shed some light about what's going on here?

Comment: You're running ssh with the "-v" parameter. Does it print any debugging output when curl connects to the socks proxy port?

Comment: Hi @Kenster, Just edited my question per your request. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 6):

maybe it is because domain address resolved to **IPv6**, and your socks5 proxy does not support that.

in this case, `curl --ipv4 ...` will work properly